# lag to get first non null value since the previous null value

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, lag, window-functions

Below is an example of what I'm trying to achieve in a Redshift Database.

I have a variable `current_value` and I want to create a new column `value_desired` that is:

- the same as `current_value` if the previous row is null
- equal to the last preceding non-null value if the previous row is non-null

It sounds like an easy task but I haven't found a way to do it yet.

```
row_numb     current_value   value_desired
1
2
3            47              47
4
5            45              45
6
7
8            42              42
9            41              42
10           40              42
11           39              42
12           38              42
13
14           36              36
15
16
17           33              33
18           32              33
```

I've tried with the LAG() function but I can only get the previous value (not the first in the "non-null" block), here is my take:

```
SELECT *
    , CASE WHEN current_value is not null and LAG(current_value) is null THEN current_value
           WHEN current_value is not null and LAG(current_value) is not null 
            THEN LAG(current_value)
      ELSE NULL END AS value_desired
  FROM test1
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: See [coalesce](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) function.

Comment: please can you update the question to say "lag to get first non null value since the previous null value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct answer, which gives the right results.
There are a few clever tricks here, i suggest you take a careful look through and let me know what needs clarifications

create test data, as per your question.

```
drop table if exists test_table ;
create table test_table (row_num int,current_value int);
insert into test_table(row_num, current_value)
values
  (1,null),
(2,null),
(3,47),
(4,null),
(5,45),
(6,null),
(7,null),
(8 ,42),
(9 ,41),
(10,40  ),
(11,39 ),
(12,38 ),
(13,null),
(14,36),
(15,null),
(16,null),
(17 ,33),
(18,32  )
;
```

Then run this code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  j1.row_num,
  CASE WHEN j1.current_value IS NULL
    THEN NULL
  ELSE
    last_value(j2.current_value)
    OVER (
      PARTITION BY j1.row_num
      ORDER BY j2.row_num
      ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING ) END AS value_desired
FROM test_table AS j1
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
               row_num,
               current_value,
               lag(current_value, 1)
               OVER (
                 ORDER BY row_num ) AS prev_cval
             FROM test_table) AS j2
    ON j1.row_num >= j2.row_num AND j2.current_value IS NOT NULL
       AND j2.prev_cval IS NULL
ORDER BY j1.row_num;
```

Answer (score 2):

Our test data

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table;
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  row_num       INT,
  current_value INT
);

INSERT INTO test_table (row_num, current_value)
VALUES
  (1, NULL),
  (2, NULL),
  (3, 47),
  (4, NULL),
  (5, 45),
  (6, NULL),
  (7, NULL),
  (8, 42),
  (9, 41),
  (10, 40),
  (11, 39),
  (12, 38),
  (13, NULL),
  (14, 36),
  (15, NULL),
  (16, NULL),
  (17, 33),
  (18, 32);
```

What we know:

- when *current_value* is not null and preceding *current_value* is null, *desired_value* is equal *current_value*

  - let's refer to this as *first_desired_value*, as per *q_first_desired_value* subquery below
  - when that *first_desired_value* is not null, it is our *desired_value*
  - we just need to propagate that *first_desired_value* to other rows, when current_value is not null
- when *current_value* is not null, desired value is **the last** first_desired_value from all preceding rows (beside the current row) and excluding NULL values that might have been added in previous frames

Given the above, the query would be as follows

```
WITH q_first_desired_value AS
(
    SELECT
      row_num,
      current_value,
      CASE WHEN LAG(current_value, 1)
                OVER (
                  ORDER BY row_num ) IS NULL
        THEN current_value
      ELSE NULL END AS first_desired_value
    FROM test_table
    ORDER BY row_num
)
SELECT
  row_num,
  current_value,
  CASE WHEN first_desired_value IS NOT NULL
    THEN first_desired_value
  WHEN current_value IS NOT NULL
    THEN LAST_VALUE(first_desired_value) IGNORE NULLS
    OVER (
    ORDER BY row_num ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING ) END AS desired_value
FROM q_first_desired_value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use FIRST_VALUE() instead of LAG()

refer: [**FIRST_VALUE and LAST_VALUE Window Functions**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_first_value.html)

Comment: this is not the answer to the question - but may be helpful.